# can't get file to output correctly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fstream

i am writing this very simple program that ouputes hello world using files. keep in mind i want the hello and world to be on separate lines.

here is the following code:

```
    int main()
    {


        std::ofstream someFile("file.dat");
        someFile << "" << std::endl;

        std::fstream someOtherFile("file.dat",ios::in | ios::out);

        std::string content;

        someOtherFile << "hello" << std::endl;
        someOtherFile << "world" << std::endl;
        someOtherFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        std::getline(someOtherFile, content);
        std::cout << content << std::endl;
        return 0;


       }
```

however, whenever i run the following program, it only prints "hello".

any help will be greatly appreciated, and PLEASE give an example using fstream, not ofstream or ifstream (I am trying to learn how fstream works, however am finding a little trouble).

my compiler is the latest VS.

Comment: you didn't close  file.dat and requesting to open second time. Is this intentional?

Comment: I don't think this code will compile, so I doubt it's the code you're actually contending with. I can guess what the problem might be, but without the real code I can only guess.

Comment: code compiles fine, output is just not correct.

Comment: If you want it to print "hello world" then why add `std::endl` because that adds a new line to the end. Thus "hello" and "world" are on separate lines. and `getline` returns the first line

Comment: Really? What is `name`?

Comment: i want to print: "Hello" and "world" on seperate lines

Comment: name is not even declared in the code or you haven't given the compelte code.

Comment: sorry, 11:30 where i  am, and this is the full thing. sorry, but i was just running a little test program.

Comment: Sorry if I've gotten anyone mad, but am a beginner programmer. So please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getine` function only read one line per one time, so you should call `getline` until the end of file. The code be below can help you.

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>`
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{


 std::ofstream someFile("file.dat");
 someFile << "" << std::endl;

 std::fstream someOtherFile("file.dat",ios::in | ios::out);

 std::string content;

 someOtherFile << "hello" << std::endl;
 someOtherFile << "world" << std::endl;
 someOtherFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
 while(std::getline(someOtherFile, content))
 {

  std::cout << content << std::endl;
 }
 
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 lines of code:

```
someOtherFile << "hello" << std::endl;
someOtherFile << "world" << std::endl;
```

They put 2 lines of strings into file.dat:

```
// file.dat
hello
world
```

The function "getline()" gets only 1 line from the file. And the "seekg" function sets the read position to the first line of the file: which contains "hello".

If you want to read to the end of the file: then replace:

```
std::getline(someOtherFile, content);
std::cout << content << std::endl;
```

with:

```
while (!someOtherFile.eof())
{
    std::getline(someOtherFile, content);
    std::cout << content << std::endl;
}
```

Or use a counter variable if you just want specific lines.

By the way, I am just assuming that you meant to put the variable "content" where "name" is.

Answer (score 0):

std::getline only get one line of text from the specific file. As http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline says:

> `istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str);`
>
> Extracts characters from `is` and stores them into `str` until the delimitation character delim is found (or the newline character, '\n', for (2)).

Answer (score 0):

Add another getline(..) and cout statement  after the first set of getline and cout. you will get the world as output.

```
someOtherFile << "hello" << std::endl;
        someOtherFile << "world" << std::endl;
        someOtherFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        std::getline(someOtherFile, content);
        std::cout << content << std::endl;
std::getline(someOtherFile, content);
        std::cout << content << std::endl;
```

getline gets only one line in a file. To get next line, you need to call again.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

  int main()
    {


        std::ofstream someFile("file.dat");
        someFile << "" << std::endl;

        someFile.close();

        std::fstream someOtherFile("file.dat",ios::in | ios::out);

        std::string content;

        someOtherFile << "hello ";
        someOtherFile << "world" << std::endl;
        someOtherFile.close();

        someOtherFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        std::getline(someFile1, content);
        std::cout << content << std::endl;

        someFile1.close();
        return 0;


       }
```

This will print your desired answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer